# Emgu Cv matchtemplate for millions of images in c#?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching, emgucv, template-matching

```
Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

I have millions of pictures as source . Its taking lot of time. Is there any solutions to make it quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy steps you can take to speed up the execution.

1. Parallelization using .Net
2. Scale down your target and model images. This must be done so that you don't lose too much details in the model.